# Reduce HTML file size?

Tags: html, c++, css

I have some code which generates a HTML file, however, if there is alot of text, the file goes well above 50mb, sometimes hitting 70-80mb.

I don't want to have a HTML file get to this size to be honest. This is the source code which defines a template of the HTML.

```
namespace Structure
{
    const std::string strHTMLTemplate = "<doctype html>"
                                        "<html lang=\"en\">"
                                        "<head>"
                                        "<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>"
                                        "<title>Data Verifier Test Results - {@testdesc}</title>"
                                        "<style>"
                                        "body {"
                                        "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F4;"
                                        "\tcolor: #1E1E1F;"
                                        "\tfont-family: \"Segoe UI\",Tahoma,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;"
                                        "\tmargin: 0;"
                                        "\tpadding: 0;"
                                        "}"
                                        "h1 {"
                                        "\tbackground-color: #E2E2E2;"
                                        "\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #C1C1C2;"
                                        "\tcolor: #201F20;"
                                        "\tfont-size: 24pt;"
                                        "\tfont-weight: normal;"
                                        "\tmargin: 0;"
                                        "\tpadding: 10px 0 10px 10px;"
                                        "}"
                                        "h2 {"
                                        "\tfont-size: 21pt;"
                                        "\tfont-weight: normal;"
                                        "\tmargin: 0;"
                                        "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
                                        "}"
                                        "h3 {"
                                        "\tbackground-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
                                        "\tfont-size: 18pt;"
                                        "\tfont-weight: normal;"
                                        "\tmargin: 0;"
                                        "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
                                        "}"
                                        "h4 {"
                                        "\tbackground-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
                                        "\tfont-size: 15pt;"
                                        "\tfont-weight: normal;"
                                        "\tmargin: 0;"
                                        "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
                                        "}"
                                        "h5 {"
                                        "\tbackground-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
                                        "\tfont-size: 12pt;"
                                        "\tfont-weight: normal;"
                                        "\tmargin: 0;"
                                        "\tpadding: 15px 0 5px;"
                                        "}"
                                        "a {"
                                        "\tcolor: #1382CE;"
                                        "}"
                                        "table {"
                                        "\tborder-collapse: collapse;"
                                        "\tborder-spacing: 0;"
                                        "\tfont-size: 8pt;"
                                        "}"
                                        "table th {"
                                        "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7E7E8;"
                                        "\tfont-weight: normal;"
                                        "\tpadding: 1px 2px;"
                                        "\ttext-align: left;"
                                        "\ttext-decoration: none;"
                                        "}"
                                        "table td {"
                                        "\tbackground: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F8;"
                                        "\tborder: 1px solid #E7E7E8;"
                                        "\tmargin: 0;"
                                        "\tpadding: 1px 2px 1px 1px;"
                                        "\tvertical-align: top;"
                                        "}"
                                        ""
                                        ".textCentered {"
                                        "\ttext-align: center;"
                                        "}"
                                        ".messageCell {"
                                        "\twidth: 100;"
                                        "}"
                                        "#content {"
                                        "\tpadding: 0 12px 12px;"
                                        "}"
                                        "#overview table {"
                                        "\tmax-width: 75;"
                                        "\twidth: auto;"
                                        "}"
                                        "#messages table {"
                                        "\twidth: 97;"
                                        "}"
                                        "</style>"
                                        "</head>"
                                        "<body>"
                                        "<div id=\"big_wrapper\">"
                                        "\t<h1>Test Results - {@testdesc}</h1>"
                                        "\t"
                                        "{@eeddata}"
                                        "\t"
                                        "</body>"
                                        "</html>";

   const std::string strHTMLEEDDataEntireMsgTemplate = "\t"
                                        "\t\t<h2 _locID=\"EEDInfo\">{@indveeddata}</h2>"
                                        "{@clientdata}"
                                        "\t";

   const std::string strHTMLEEDDataTemplate = "\t"
                                        "{@clientdata}"
                                        "\t";

   const std::string strHTMLRequestTemplate = "\t\t<h2 _locID=\"ReqInfo\">Request Information</h2>"
                                        "\t\t<div id=\"ReqInfoResults\">"
                                        "\t\t</div>"
                                        "\t\t<div id=\"ReqValueResults\">"
                                        "\t\t<h3 _locID=\"RequestDataTitle\">Request Data</h3>"
                                        "\t\t\t<table>"
                                        "{@requestbody}"
                                        "\t\t\t</table>"
                                        "\t\t</div>";

   const std::string strHTMLResponseTemplate = "\t\t<h2 _locID=\"ResponseTitle\">Response Results</h2>"
                                        "\t\t<div id=\"RespInfoResults\">"
                                        "\t\t</div>"
                                        "\t\t<div id=\"RespValueResults\">"
                                        "\t\t<h3 _locID=\"ResponseDataTitle\">Response Data</h3>"
                                        "\t\t\t<table>"
                                        "{@responsebody}"
                                        "\t\t\t</table>"
                                        "\t\t</div>";

   const std::string strHTMLSingleMessageTemplate = "\t\t<h4 _locID=\"MessageTitle\">RWF Message</h4>"
                                        "\t\t<div id=\"MessageResults\">"
                                        "\t\t<h5 _locID=\"ActualMessageResults\">Source: {@source} Destination: {@destination} Timestamp: {@timestamp}</h5>"
                                        "{@messagebody}"
                                        "\t\t</div>";

   const std::string strHTMLClientDataTemplate = "\t\t<h3 _locID=\"Client ID: \">{@clientid} {@subclientid}</h3>" 
                                                "{@requestmsg}"
                                                "{@responsemsg}";

   const std::string strHTMLResponseHdrTemplate =   "<tr>"
                                                    "<th></th>"
                                                    "<th _locID=\"TypeHeader\">Type</th>"
                                                    "<th _locID=\"ValueHeader\">Value</th>"
                                                    "</tr>"       
                                                    "<tr>"
                                                    "<td style=\"background: blue\"></td>"
                                                    "<td><strong>Path</strong></td>"
                                                    "<td>{@url}</td>"
                                                    "</tr>"
                                                    "<tr>"
                                                    "<td style=\"background: blue\"></td>"
                                                    "<td><strong>IP Address</strong></td>"
                                                    "<td>{@iptosendto}</td>"
                                                    "</tr>";

   const std::string strHTMLReqHdrRowTemplate =  "<tr>"
                                                "<th></th>"
                                                "{@reqhdrrowvalue}"
                                                "</tr>";

   const std::string strHTMLRespHdrRowTemplate =  "<tr>"
                                                "<th></th>"
                                                "{@resphdrrowvalue}"
                                                "</tr>";

   const std::string strHTMLReqHdrRowValueTemplate = "<th _locID=\"{@requestvaluehdr}Header\"><strong>{@requestvaluehdr}<strong></th>";

   const std::string strHTMLRespHdrRowValueTemplate = "<th _locID=\"{@responsevaluehdr}Header\"><strong>{@responsevaluehdr}<strong></th>";

   const std::string strHTMLReqDataRowTemplate = "<tr>"
                                                "<td style=\"background: blue\"></td>"
                                                "{@reqdatarowvalue}"
                                                "</tr>";

   const std::string strHTMLRespDataRowTemplate = "<tr>"
                                                "<td style=\"background: blue\"></td>"
                                                "{@respdatarowvalue}"
                                                "</tr>";

   const std::string strHTMLRespDataRowValueTemplate = "<td>{@responsevalue}</td>";
   const std::string strHTMLReqDataRowValueTemplate = "<td>{@requestvalue}</td>";

   const std::string strHTMLCLIENTDATA = "{@clientdata}";
   const std::string strHTMLEEDSDATA = "{@eeddata}";
   const std::string strHTMLINDVEEDDATA = "{@indveeddata}";

   const std::string strHTMLCLIENTID = "{@clientid}";
   const std::string strHTMLSUBCLIENTID = "{@subclientid}";

   const std::string strHTMLSOURCEIP = "{@source}";
   const std::string strHTMLDESTINATIONIP = "{@destination}";
   const std::string strHTMLTIMESTAMP = "{@timestamp}";

   const std::string strHTMLREQUESTMSG = "{@requestmsg}";
   const std::string strHTMLRESPONSEMSG = "{@responsemsg}";

   const std::string strHTMLREQUESTBODY = "{@requestbody}";
   const std::string strHTMLRESPONSEBODY = "{@responsebody}";
   const std::string strHTMLMESSAGEBODY = "{@messagebody}";

   const std::string strHTMLREQHDRROWVALUE = "{@reqhdrrowvalue}";
   const std::string strHTMLRESPHDRROWVALUE = "{@resphdrrowvalue}";

   const std::string strHTMLREQUESTHDR = "{@requesthdr}";
   const std::string strHTMLRESPONSEHDR = "{@responsehdr}";

   const std::string strHTMLREQUESTVALUEHDR = "{@requestvaluehdr}";
   const std::string strHTMLRESPONSEVALUEHDR = "{@responsevaluehdr}";

   const std::string strHTMLREQDATAROWVALUE = "{@reqdatarowvalue}";
   const std::string strHTMLRESPDATAROWVALUE = "{@respdatarowvalue}";

   const std::string strHTMLREQUESTVALUE = "{@requestvalue}";
   const std::string strHTMLRESPONSEVALUE = "{@responsevalue}";
   const std::string strHTMLTESTDESCRIPTION = "{@testdesc}";
}
```

There are over 1000 calls which use the strHTMLReqDataRowTemplate and strHTMLRespDataRowTemplate and replace the {@} tags with the necessary data. This is all done recursively.

Looking at the HTML and CSS, can you guys see any way where I can improve the output?

The HTML page should have columns and rows of data, and I am frequently creating a table with rows and columns.

Comment: You can´t "call" a variable. What you´ve shown is not the actual generation code. And a piece of the actual HTML file would be better anyways. (But don´t hope for much improvement. HTML isn´t a image where you can decrease quality as much as you want, it´s text.)

Comment: Reworded it. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the textual content, it seems to me that the `HTML/CSS` is only a small fraction of your quoted output size after your substitutions `>50mb`. So I don't think reducing the `HTML/CSS` is going to buy you anything to be honest. More relevant to *speed* might be how you *substitute* the text. I would write a pre-processor to slice the text up around the *substitution markers* and send the substitution text interleaved with the *sliced* text.

Comment: Thanks Galik. How exactly can i do that?

Comment: Well you could search the text for your *substitution markers* `{@name}` and store the  text *before* the marker and the name of the marker itself as two data members of a `struct`. Build a *vector* of those by finding all the *markers* in the document. When you send  a document you iterate through the *vector* sending the text of each element and then using the name of the substitution, send the correct substitution text.  The benefit is you don't have to search through the document to find the *substitution markers* every time you do it just once at the beginning. (hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at:

```
style=\"background: blue\">
```

Inlining a style like that consumes a lot of space. If possible, remove it completely and use CSS for instance:

```
td:nth-child(2) { ... }
```

If that is not possible, you could add a class instead of an inline style to save at least a couple of bytes:

```
<td class="data"
```

And you can even cheat a little by adding a custom attribute:

```
 <td x>Hello</td>
```

Small example of styling for that:

```css
div[x] {color: blue;}
div[y] {color: red;}
```

```html
<div x>Hello</div>
<div y>world</div>
```

However, in the end it is still a lot of data, so the best idea is maybe to choose a different format or compress the HTML file when distributing it. Even if you feed it from a web server, you may compress the response using gz, which will reduce the size dramatically, way more than micro-optimizations like the one above will do.

And note, for the browser it doesn't matter much if the element contains a full classname of my little attribute hack. In the end, the whole document needs to be loaded into memory, and the actual cells with their styling will consume a lot of memory regardless of how compact you store it on disk. There may be some difference, but not as much as you may expect.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not  the best language to do this sort of thing, but I can't help but think a massive farm of functions like this:

```
std::string strHTMLReqDataRowTemplate (const std::string & reqdatarowvalue)
{ 
    return "<tr>"
           "<td style=\"background: blue\"></td>"+
           reqdatarowvalue +
           "</tr>";
}
```

or

```
std::ostream & strHTMLReqDataRowTemplate (std::ostream & out,
                                          const std::string & reqdatarowvalue)
{
    out << "<tr>"
           "<td style=\"background: blue\"></td>";
    out << reqdatarowvalue;
    out << "</tr>";
}
```

instead of the string farm would be quicker than the search and replace of tags. Define the functions in one or more cpp files, depending on how big the library is and how you want it organized, and then all you have to expose is a header full of function definitions.